# Heroku (PlayFramework/Scala) app automatically redirect to https

Tags: mod-rewrite, heroku, https, playframework

I have an PlayFramework App developed using Scala running on Heroku; I only mention the development language and framework because any posts I've found regarding this issue relate to PHP!  I have http and https running on a custom domain but I would like to force http requests to be redirect to https.

I've found that I need to update the .htaccess file with the following:

```
##Force SSL 

#Normal way (in case you need to deploy to NON-heroku)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

#Heroku way
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 

#If neither above conditions are met, redirect to https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I am not sure if it is possible or how to set up the .htaccess file using Play and Scala.

Please can someone advise?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add

```
play.filters.enabled += play.filters.https.RedirectHttpsFilter
```

In your `.conf` file.

It will redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS automatically.

It only works in `production` mode by default. To change that, add :

```
play.filters.https.redirectEnabled = true
```

See the [RedirectHttpsFilter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/RedirectHttpsFilter)
 documentation for more.

Comment: That didn't quite work as expected.  I am using a deployment pipeline on Heroku, pushing to upstream master pushes to STAGING (only the normal herokuapp.com domain pointed at that which is already https).  I then move from STAGING to PROD after testing on STAGING.  The above filter give me an error `.herokuapp.com redirected you too many times` when attempting to hit the STAGING url.

Comment: As moving from STAGING to PROD simply copies the deployed artifact over I can not use a different .conf file per environment, which would have solved that issue.

Comment: You can use a different `.conf` file. Create a file name `Procfile` following https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionHeroku#connecting-to-a-database . Then set  `-Dconfig.resource=yourFile.conf` inside it. It will make Heroku use that  `.conf` file instead.

Comment: The Procfile is built into the deployed artifact.  The deployed artifact is simply copied from STAGING to PROD (no alteration, i.e. the same Procfile) when using the Deployment Pipeline.  So I can't have different Procfiles.

Comment: You can use an environment variable to hold the name of the conf file. Like `-Dconfig.resource=$CONFIG_FILE` and then `heroku config:set CONFIG_FILE="yourFile.conf"` in each env. Or you can put the env var in the config: `play.filters.https.redirectEnabled = ${REDIRECT_ENABLED}`